# Webpack 2 How to handle @import statement?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've have been learning how to set a reactjs project with webpack.

So I'm trying to make this project [000-landing-page](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-daily-ui/tree/master/003-landing-page) run with webpack configuration. I want to use extract-text-webpack-plugin.

But in css file there are import statements;

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900";
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

And these lines causes errors

> "unexpected character @ you may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type"

actually exception is clear but I couldn't find appropriate loader. I've installed html, file, url loaders and tried a few configurations but couldn't get it done.

these are my css and scss loaders

```
 {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules/")],
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
           loader: [
           'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
          ],
          })
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules/")],
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
             loader: [
               'postcss-loader',
               'sass-loader',
             'css-loader',
            ],
            }),
        }
```

Comment: If you remove the imports, does it work?

Comment: No, it says unexpected token you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.(this time without @import ). You can take a look at css the css file here.https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-daily-ui/blob/master/003-landing-page/src/App.css

Comment: when i remove  include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules/")], this line it works. But app.css which causes error is not in node modules it is in src directory(seperate folder).It is weird

Comment: I got one clue. Include means just include specific file path. Without it, it includes all i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had nothing to do with @symbol. I missed a tiny point due to being a beginner about webpack.

**If nothing is included using include : [] it means every files are included**

**If something is included using include : [file x] it means any files included except file x.**

since i added **" include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules/")],** " it only includes node_modules not my src folder.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the loader order is right-to-left. This would make the loader array for the scss to be:

`['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']`

This is because it is essentially a composed function i.e.
`css(postcss(sass(file)))`